# Can I create custom blocks in bookdown without new paragraph <p> added?

Tags: bookdown

I am using `bookdown` and trying to create a custom block, where I would insert a fixed text before the text, e.g. insert the word "Question:" before my text. I'd like it to look like this:

Question: What is the point of this?

I've tried to do the following

````
    ```{block, type="QUESTION"}
    What is the point of this?
    ```
````

And I've made CSS style file:

```
    .QUESTION {
      font-style: italic;
      display: inline-block;
    }
    .QUESTION:before {
      font-weight: bold;
      content: "Question:";
    }
```

The problem is that `bookdown` (or pandoc?) encloses the text in the block with  `<p>` and `</p>` so it's not on one line and I get:

Question:

What is the point of all this?

i.e., the html looks like this:

```
    <div class="QUESTION">
    <p>
    What is the point of this?
    </p>
    </div>
```

If I manually delete the `<p>` code from the html or put the `<div>` statement inside of the `<p>` brackets, it looks like what I was hoping for.

Is there a way to make these inline (like inline r code) within bookdown?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I strongly recommend using fenced `Div` blocks instead of the `block` engine of **knitr**. You can find [more information about the former here](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/custom-blocks.html). For your question, the `Div` block will be:

````
```{css, echo=FALSE}
.QUESTION {
  font-style: italic;
  display: inline-block;
}
.QUESTION > :first-child:before {
  font-weight: bold;
  content: "Question: ";
}
```

::: {.QUESTION} 
What is the point of this?

Another paragraph.
:::
````

Comment: I tried using this code, but it still generated the `<p>` tag inside the `<div class='QUESTION'>`.

Comment: @epurdom Sorry! You are correct. I just updated the answer. Instead of adding `Question:` before the div, you could add it to the first child element of the div. Would that work for you?

Comment: Yes! Thanks so much! Just for clarity for others who might find this answer, adding this to the css style file (or above in the `css` block as @yihui-xie does) also works for the block engine approach in my original question, too.